# File Excel From Apache POI Cant Open by Ms Excel (corrupt)

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I don't know why the file I write using POI cant be opened by Ms Excel 2013, but the file is still readable by POI. (cell value can be changed)

[this](http://i59.tinypic.com/200eoua.png) is the error from file

here is the code

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileUri); //not error at fileUri
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String urii = fileUri.replace(".xls", "0.xls"); //not error
    File fisx = new File(urii);

    Workbook workbook = null;
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row = sheet.getRow(0);

    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

    String p = cell.getStringCellValue();

    TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUri);

    cell.setCellValue(new String("popo"));
    String x = cell.getStringCellValue();

    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFile);

    a.setText(p);
    b.setText(x);

    OutputStream fos = null;

    fos = new FileOutputStream(fisx);
    workbook.write(fos); //main problem
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 7):

There are two issues with your code. Firstly this:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(fileUri);
```

As explained in the [Apache POI Docs, don't use an InputStream if you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Secondly, this:

```
 Workbook workbook = null;
 workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

That will only work for `.xls` files, not for `.xlsx` ones. Instead, you need to use [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) which identifies the type and gives you the right workbook for the format

So, change your code to be

```
File file = new File(fileUri);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Comment: I still get the same error, the original File's size is 25kb, but the output File's size just 17kb (with the same content or maybe a few different)

Comment: Make sure you're saving to a different file. POI doesn't (currently) support in-place writes, so it needs to be a different file

Comment: String urii = fileUri.replace(".xls", "0.xls"); this line for change the uri and name file, please help meeeeeee..... :((

Comment: I try the code in the java project, it works fine, but when I use this code to android project (using bluestack emulator) give error output (corrupt file)

Comment: How do the two files differ? Sadly it sounds like an Android bug though, if it works in regular Java...

Comment: bug from emulator (maybe), using real android device doesn't give me error file output, I was using bluestack emulator

Answer (score 2):

The major problem that i see here is:

```
Workbook workbook = null;
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Instead you have to use:

```
Workbook workbook = null;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

TO be readable by MS EXCEL 2013.

Comment: yes..but to be able to be opened on MS Excel 2013 you need to use...XSSFWorkbook

Comment: my input file is xls type and the output is xls type too.. Also, I have tried to upload the output file to google docs, and failed to upload (I think because the output file is corrupt)

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi I need to write the file type as xlsx for which I use FileOutputStream class. Can you suggest the way to write the file using the right workbook class

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

by using real android device instead of bluestack emulator,
I dont know why, but it works!!

Thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getSheetAt(0) but you did not create any sheet before (workbook.createSheet(“name”)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use the .xls extension and NOT .xlsx, as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833979/excel-file-created-with-apache-poi-java-cant-be-opened-on-windows)