# xlsx file created in my java code is not opening in ms excel, says the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a java code to create a excel file and it works fine for the extensions .xls and .xlsx I'm able to open .xls file but unable to open the file extension .xlsx in ms excel and it says ***Excel cannot open the 'sample.xlsx' file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.***

Below is my java code I used.

```
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
String file = "D:/sample.xlsx";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
workBook.write(fos);
fos.flush();
```

I have gone thru the below link which looked like having similar issue but I didn't find the answer so raised here as new question.
[File Excel From Apache POI Cant Open by Ms Excel (corrupt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397347/file-excel-from-apache-poi-cant-open-by-ms-excel-corrupt)

Comment: `HSSFWorkbook` ==> `*.xls`. `XSSFWorkbook` ==> `*.xlsx`. And a workbook needs at least one sheet.

Comment: @AxelRichter XSSFWorkBook constructor don't accept FileOutputStream object, so unable to proceed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're attempting to create an Excel file with the .xlsx extension, you need to use the XSSFWorkbook. I suggest reading [this](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html) to understand the difference between the XSSFWorkbook and the HSSFWorkbook objects.

Further, you can use the documentation [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) to figure out how to make a new Excel file using Apache POI.

Essentially, you'll be doing this:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Thanks francis, sure I'll try it out and share the feedback. +1 for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked. You should mark my answer as correct so that your question no longer appears unanswered.