# Apache POI generates corrupted Excel File

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxl

I am using Apache POI to create an excel file with the help of database. I tried searching a lot with different codes and all I got was corrupted excel sheet over and over again. As of now, here is the code which I am using:

```
    public void  generateExcel(ResultSet rs, String excelFilename, String newDesc){

    try {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Cell c = null;
        //Cell style for header row
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex());
        cs.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        Font f = wb.createFont();
        f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        f.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        cs.setFont(f);

        //New Sheet
        Sheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1 = wb.createSheet(newDesc);


        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

        //Create Hash Map of Field Definitions
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, MyTableInfo> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, MyTableInfo>(colCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            MyTableInfo db2TableInfo = new MyTableInfo(); 
            db2TableInfo.setFieldName(metaData.getColumnName(i + 1).trim());
            db2TableInfo.setFieldText(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
            db2TableInfo.setFieldSize(metaData.getPrecision(i + 1));
            db2TableInfo.setFieldDecimal(metaData.getScale(i + 1));
            db2TableInfo.setFieldType(metaData.getColumnType(i + 1));
            db2TableInfo.setCellStyle(getCellAttributes(wb, c, db2TableInfo));
            hashMap.put(i, db2TableInfo);
        }

        // Row and column indexes
        int idx = 0;
        int idy = 0;

        // Generate column headings
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(idx);
        MyTableInfo db2TableInfo = new MyTableInfo();

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = (Integer) iterator.next();
            db2TableInfo = hashMap.get(key); 
            c = row.createCell(idy);
            c.setCellValue(db2TableInfo.getFieldText());
            c.setCellStyle(cs);
            if(db2TableInfo.getFieldSize() > db2TableInfo.getFieldText().trim().length()){
                sheet1.setColumnWidth(idy, (db2TableInfo.getFieldSize()* 500));
            }
            else {
                sheet1.setColumnWidth(idy, (db2TableInfo.getFieldText().trim().length() * 500));
            }
            idy++;
        }

        while (rs.next()) {

            idx++;
            row = sheet1.createRow(idx);
            System.out.println(idx);
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                c = row.createCell(i);
                db2TableInfo = hashMap.get(i);

                switch (db2TableInfo.getFieldType()) {
                case 1:
                    c.setCellValue(rs.getString(i+1));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    c.setCellValue(rs.getDouble(i+1));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    c.setCellValue(rs.getDouble(i+1));
                    break;
                default:
                    c.setCellValue(rs.getString(i+1));
                    break;
                }
                c.setCellStyle(db2TableInfo.getCellStyle());
            }

        }

        rs.close();


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFilename);

        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}


private static CellStyle getCellAttributes (Workbook wb, Cell c, MyTableInfo db2TableInfo){

    CellStyle cs= wb.createCellStyle();
    DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
    Font f = wb.createFont();

    switch (db2TableInfo.getFieldDecimal()) {
    case 1:
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.0"));
        break;
    case 2:
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        break;
    case 3:
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.000"));
        break;
    case 4:
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.0000"));
        break;
    case 5:
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.00000"));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cs.setFont(f);

    return cs;

}
```

I get the following message:

```
"Excel cannot open the file "filename" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."
```

I used to generate excel files using JXL earlier but recently it started giving me the same thing too hence i opted to switch to Apache POI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is filename extension you are passing in generateExcel to be wriiten?

Comment: i use xlsx extension

Comment: Ok. You can try    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file) instead of workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397347/file-excel-from-apache-poi-cant-open-by-ms-excel-corrupt   Hope this may help.

Comment: I dont see any `FileInputStream` being used here. the workbook is being created correctly. @JazzzzOut can you try to remove all formatting form the code? This would also include column width etc. If that doesn't help at all, then try to also remove the data (create an empty workbook with 1 sheet, 1 row and 1 cell with simple content). This way we can see where exactly the problem lies

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I did try using a very simple query and it worked with the same code. The FileInputStream was not needed mentioned [stackoverflow.com/questions/30397347](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397347/file-excel-from-apache-poi-cant-open-by-ms-excel-corrupt)

Comment: @HKG I tried with it as you said. Still didnt worked

Comment: How I understand it, you are then having a problem with the actual data you try to insert. without providing that data, we can't help you

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i tried making a standalone class and it worked when i tried to open on my hard coded file path. It seems to be creating problems when the file is to be downloaded from a jsp page

Comment: So you have a JSP from which you download the newly generated excel file? In that case, save the excel file on the server or wherever you run the JSP and access it from there. Maybe just your download method isn't implemented properly

Comment: I got the problem. neither did my jxl or poi through generated excel had a problem. It was with jsp download servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpServletResponse has been setted correctly?
What file extension are you using?

Try with this:

```
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"example.xls\"");

workbook = getWorkbook(....)

workbook.write(os);
workbook.close();
os.flush();

response.flushBuffer();
```

Where 'response' is a HttpServletResponse from the controller method

Comment: I am using xlsx extenstion. Also I am not using HttpServletResponse. I just call a java object in this case with method generateExcel passing parameters.

Comment: May I know what would getWorkBook have if i use xls format.

Comment: You can use Workbook or HSSFWorkbook for .xls format.

Workbook is the common interface, which works for both HSSF (.xls) and XSSF (.xlsx)
HSSFWorkbook is the implementation of Workbook for .xls format.

For more details -> http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html